# JQuery wait until an element has hidden before continuing

Tags: javascript, jquery, hide, wait, slideup

My Jquery code is as follows:

```
if($('#LoginFormError').is(':visible'))$('#LoginFormError').slideUp();
//Check inputs and run ajax
if(CheckInput('#LoginUsername') && CheckInput('#LoginPassword')){
    $('#LoginSubmit').attr('disabled', true);
    $.ajax({
        (..ajax stuf..)
    });
}else{
    $('#LoginFormError').html("Please fill in everything.");
    $('#LoginFormError').slideDown();
}
```

For the purpose of this, CheckInput returns true if the field is filled in.

What I want to do is if then #LoginFormError is visible, for the script to hide the element and then run the check procedures. The issue is though that #LoginFormError may not be visible at all, so I can't put everything into the call back from the SlideUp function, although I don't think I can.

Comment: Can you explain better why you can't put it in a callback? The callback to `slideUp` is called immediately if the element is already hidden.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the callback will always be called (even if the element is already hidden) there's no need to check. Just put everything in the callback:

```
$('#LoginFormError').slideUp(400, function{
        //Check inputs and run ajax
        if(CheckInput('#LoginUsername') && CheckInput('#LoginPassword')){
            $('#LoginSubmit').attr('disabled', true);
            $.ajax({
                (..ajax stuf..)
            });
        }else{
            $('#LoginFormError').html("Please fill in everything.");
            $('#LoginFormError').slideDown();
        }
    }
);
```